# Test Automation tool able to determine object properties in desktop based application made with Ruby

Tags: automated-testing, ruby, desktop-application

I have to test a desktop application for Windows which was written in Ruby. I need to be able to inspect object properties.

So far I have tried:

- UFT - it is unable to identify objects or properties
- Winium - UISpy and Inspect are unable to identify objects or properties
- TestComplete - unable to identify objects or properties.

What tools are available that can inspect objects and their properties in a Ruby Windows application?

Comment: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/125687/34069

Comment: This is a great question.  No idea why the downvotes.

Comment: Use SikuliX, it works like charm for any UI desktop/web/mobile automation
http://sikulix.com

Answer (score 2):

I write test suites in Ruby using Rspec and Selenium. This does not mean that I must use Ruby to write automated tests for code written in Ruby. There's no need to choose your automation tool based on the fact that your application is written in Ruby. However, if you are looking for automation tools/frameworks for automating tests in Ruby then Rspec with Selenium is a popular choice that has plenty of online documentation.

There are tools and frameworks that are geared towards specific languages -Protractor for angularJS, Jasmine for javascript, etc - but not so much of a concern for Ruby.

Its a broad question but perhaps this provides a little insight for you.

Comment: I just need a tool to automate a desktop app made with Ruby since UFT cannot identify its objects